# Raspberry Pi and iOS app communication using BLE

Tags: ios, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, hm-10

I'm developing an iOS app that should communicate with a Raspberry Pi to send and receive simple data.
I've researched a little bit and found out that making this connection using BLE would be the correct way, as my project cannot depend on network signal (in this case I could use MQTT or some socket approach).

My doubt is, which BLE module for raspberry would work with iOS and Core Bluetooth framework?
Would HM-10 work?

Comment: Which version of the Raspberry Pi are we talking about? The newer versions come with an already equiped Bluetooth module

Comment: It's a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B

Answer (score 1):

The Raspberry Pi 4b is capable of Bluetooth 5 and therefore capable of Bluetooth Low Energy. There is no need for additional hardware. There is a great answer below [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73178361/7473793) by @ukBaz regarding the usage of BLE and the D-Bus API on a Raspberry Pi